# how to create an auto suggest box in zkoss framework

Tags: java, zk

Is there is any component for auto suggest similar to google suggest or can any one tell me how can i implement it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto-suggest is usually done using the data-structures [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) or [radix-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree).Here is a good [implementation of radix tree](http://code.google.com/p/radixtree/).For zk frame work check this [link](http://www.zkoss.org/smalltalks/autocomplete/autocomplete.dsp).